# How to inform user about the result of a GET/POST request on iphone?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nsurlconnection

I need to inform my user about the result of the GET process whether the data is sent to server or not. Can anyone give me an idea about how to do?

Note: In one of my User Interfaces there are some buttons, and when the user clicks them some data will be sent to server. How can i inform user about this request's result? Thanks..

**EDIT**

```
-(IBAction)theAction:(id)sender{

    NSString *key1=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"keyToKey"];
    NSString *userID=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userID"];
     NSLog(@"\nButton ID: %d-",[sender tag] );
    NSString *str1= [[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:serverF.text] stringByAppendingString:@"/request.php?"];
    NSString *str2= [[str1 stringByAppendingString:@"key="] stringByAppendingString:key1];
    NSString *str3= [[[[str2 stringByAppendingString:@"&userID="]stringByAppendingString:userID] stringByAppendingString:@"&button_tag="]stringByAppendingString:[ sender tag]];
    NSURL *theUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:str3];

  // What shall i do from here?, or is this way true???



}
```

What do i need from this point?

Comment: Are you using NSURLConnection? Give us a bit more details about how you're sending that data over to your server, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this code you will have at the `GETresponse` the result for the GET HTTP request:

```
    NSString *GETresponse=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Note, that this is synchronous request if I am right, so it will block UI thread, which is mentioned in question. Better solution may be use of [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755) with `+ sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

Comment: This is exactly the answer, you can edit the question with it:) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easy way how to do it comfortably is use ASI HTTP. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use
Then result of your request is in:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

in case your request finished successfuly, or

```
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

in case it failed. You can choose queue, sync and async requests, as you like.

Comment: Thanks for rhat but i faced some problems with ASIHTTPRequest Library in my app. Isn't there any other way please?

Comment: Yes it is, use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755) with `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same string with this single method:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"http://%@/request.php?key=%@&userID=%@&button_tag=%@",
                serverF.text, key1, userID, [sender tag] ];
```

Comment: A wise sollution :D but i wish this was answer to my question:)